# How can I fetch last row of the array in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= m.members %>
```

This gives back this array below. If I want to get only last row of this array(Ray's record), how can I code?

```
[#<User id: 4, username: "John", age: 27, deleted_at: nil>, 
#<User id: 8, username: "Mike", age: 27, deleted_at: nil>,
#<User id: 13, username: "Ray", age: 27, deleted_at: nil>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[#<User id: 4, username: "John", age: 27, deleted_at: nil>, 
#<User id: 8, username: "Mike", age: 27, deleted_at: nil>,
#<User id: 13, username: "Ray", age: 27, deleted_at: nil>].last
```

If we want to get the last and first elements as follows: 
Ex: **arr = [1,2,3,4]** 
$> **arr.last => 4** 
$> **arr.first =>  1**

Comment: Thanks for reply:) I tried it before but it gives back <User:0x00000017d55298> :(

Comment: please write `.inspect` after that.

Comment: The default `to_s` method for Array is the same as `inspect` in Ruby 1.9. An individual element's `to_s` method may be different. You shouldn't be dumping raw records into your HTML anyway, but instead accessing specific properties. `to_yaml` or `to_json` often provides a more readable output.

Comment: Also: `[1,2,3,4][-1] #=> 4`